# Windows Phone 7 map control: panning the map while keeping the pushpin constant

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on a WP7 (mango) app which has a Bing Maps control with one pushpins on the screen. I need to be able to drag/pan the map so that the map view changes while the pushpin remains in a constant position relative on the screen. How can I achieve this? The pin always seems to be attached to the map and moves with the map.

(This is basically an alternative to dragging the pushpin around the map i.e. dragging the map around the pushpin).

Comment: You cannot keep a pin in the same spot when the user drags a map.  Should be obvious.  Maybe you are talking about *zooming* a map?

Comment: I mean I'd like the pushpin to remain constant relative to the _physical_ screen of the device, if that makes sense.

What I'm trying to achieve is a essentially a draggable pushpin, and there are two ways to do that: Either 1) move the pushpin itself or 2) move the map underneath the pushpin leaving the pushpin where it was relative to the margins of the map. In my case, it's more user-friendly to adjust the map, as opposed to the pushpin (pushpin is too small/awkward to drag around).

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a `Location` to the Pushpin. Instead just set it's `Margin` to the values you want. The margins are calculated from the absolute center of the Map control

That way it'll be in a fixed position. Alternatively, you can add the map on a Canvas, and just draw any element on top of the Canvas.

But why you want to do this, I really cannot imagine.

Normally a Pushpin is fixed according to a GeoLocation (a GPS coordinate), and stays at that fixed point, when you pan/drag/zoom the map. That's what the `Pushpin.Location` property/attribute is for.